# AVPlayerView shows video locally, but not from IP Camera - OS X

Tags: swift, macos, rtsp, ip-camera, avplayerview

What I am trying to do here is connect to an IP Camera and display the stream/feed using the AVPlayView.

If I play a local video everything is working fine:

```
 let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video-bg", ofType: "mp4")
 let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
 playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
 player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
//Display Stream on AVPlayerView 
self.avPlayerView.player = player
```

**But** when I am trying to connect to a camera using the following code it does not work:

```
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("http://96.10.1.168/")
playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
//Display the stream       
self.avPlayerView.player = player
```

- This is a public IP Camera found from **Google** and it works on my browser.
- info.plist is edited to allow connection:

  ```
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
      <key>http://96.10.1.168/</key>
      <dict>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
          <string>TLSv1.1</string>
      </dict>
  </dict>
  ```

It seems that I am approaching this wrong, so can somebody **point me** to the right direction and tell what is the **correct approach?**

Answer (score 0):

The page at `http://96.10.1.168/` returns HTML, it doesn't return a video stream.

There's JavaScript in the page's HTML, and this JavaScript is what loads the video in your browser.

You can not use `http://96.10.1.168/` directly with AVPlayer.

Comment: So what do I do when I want to access the IP camera which I know it's ip address and I want to play it using AVPlayerView? thank you for you answer.

Comment: You can use AVPlayer only if you know the video stream's URL. Here, you don't know it, because the Web Camera doesn't generate a video stream at all, it's all done in JavaScript in the page: you just can't use AVPlayer.